# Python - How to run python script in a specific tty, in Linux?

Tags: python, switch-statement, tty

In the project, I shall boot to the Linux console mode (init 3), and then run a python script using curses library (with console UI) in a specific tty.

For example, OS boots to tty 0, and I type:

> sudo chvt 2 && sudo python /root/aaa.py

This is Ubuntu Live Desktop OS, so sudo would not prompt for password and just execute the command with elevated privilage.

The tty does switch to 2, but /root/aaa.py (with curses library UI) is executed in tty 0...

If I want the script is executed in tty 2 and the UI is shown in tty 2, how to do it?

Many thanks.

Comment: This isn't really a Python question…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [openvt](http://man.cx/openvt) command is what you're looking for.  Remember that you'll need root privileges to execute it.

Comment: Additional Information: calling "openvt -s -- <some_command>" does bring the screen to the first available TTY. But the python curses UI is interrupted by TTY login words, i.e., "Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ......". My solution is, at the very begging of the python script, write "time.sleep(10)" and "myscr = curses.initscr()" and "myscr.clear()". This will make the screen clear when displaying what you wanna display.